# IsolationLevel to lock table C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

i'm trying to lock the table som other client can't change in it until i'm done but its not working. i have create 2 projekt, both is exactly the same. i start those project at a same time. when i chose the table it should lock that table but the other projekt still can get the table and make change. here is the code i have done.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
con.Open();
SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WITH (TABLOCK,HOLDLOCK)", con);
_Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
_Command = con.CreateCommand();
SqlTransaction _Transaction = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);            
_Command.Connection = con;
_Command.Transaction = _Transaction ;

public void Commit()
    {
        _Command.CommandText = "UPDATE " + table + " SET " + column[1] + " = '" +
                            txtBox1.Text + "', " + column[2] + " = '" +
                            txtBox2.Text + "', " + column[3] + " = '" +
                            txtBox3.Text + "', " + column[4] + " = '" +
                            txtBox4.Text + "' WHERE " + column[0] + " = " + txtBox0.Text;
        _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (_Transaction != null)
        {
            _Transaction .Commit();
        }
    }
```

public void commit is for later on when i'm done with the change.

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# method to lock SQL Server table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712926/c-sharp-method-to-lock-sql-server-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the modern syntax for what you're attempting.  Also, according to the documentation, you shouldn't require table hints with IsolationLevel.Serializable.  To maintain your lock, you need to create your transaction before selecting from the first query.

When using TransactionScopes, the framework will automatically enroll connections in open transactions and automatically rollback if scope.Complete() hasn't been called.  I.e. An error occurred or you skipped scope.Complete() because of some failed verification.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
var options = new TransactionOptions();
options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable;

using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
{
    var something = ReadSomething();
    WriteSomething(something);
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: hi i have move my code into the scope like u created. the only different is scope.complete i have it in commit but still not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try use TABLOCKX :

```
SELECT * FROM table (TABLOCKX)
```

The above command will queue other reads and updates outside your transaction until the transaction commite or rolled back